# What Christian groups believe sex was the original sin, and not disobedience?

Tags: genesis, denomination-survey, adam-and-eve, fall-of-man, sex-acts

There is a story in the Bible that Adam and Eve ate the fruit and thus sinned against God. But other religions, including some Christians, describe that they were having intercourse and that's why God threw them out of the garden. Which Christian groups believe this, and what is their reasoning?

Comment: The Bible never say that. I'm curious which Christian group interpret it in such manner.

Comment: Do you have any references for this teaching?  In the creation account, God specifically commands Adam and Eve to be fruitful and multiply and fill the earth.  There really is only one way to do that, and that is to have intercourse.  So, intercourse was not only God's idea, but God's plan and God's intent for marriage.  So, no, that idea is completely unbiblical.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: @Narnian Whoops, I just saw that my answer is identical to your comment. And that's why I should read the comments first.

Comment: @jlaverde No problem.  It is the answer.

Comment: You **could** always pick up the bible and read it

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more on-topic for this site. I think it's a good question; there are a minority of Christian groups that hold (or held) this view.  I believe the Shakers may have fallen into this category (but they don't exist any more, since they forbade sex).

Comment: @Flimzy Well done. This is now a question that is on-topic *and* interesting. Last I checked, [there are actually three living remaining Shakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakers#Modern-day_Shakers) and their demise is more due to the fact that the state now prohibits religious groups from adopting children.

Comment: @Narnian You know, I don't have a reference either, but I've heard not only this, but that oral sex, specifically, was the first sin. That was a decade ago on a web forum though.

Comment: If sex is a sin, then the first sin, would have been lust... not sex... :P

Comment: @Flimzy Catechism of the Catholic Church goes along that line too, it was "mark by lust and domination" (CCC400). Could it really be a sexual act? Let's wait for the answer as my previous answer was unfairly deleted by Peter Turner.

Comment: @jongricafort According to Catholicism, "lust" has been an issue since the fall. They explicitly say Adam and Eve "could have" had sex without lust.

Comment: @disciple Yes, CCC398 teaches that Adam & Eve must be "divinized" first meaning must reach Theosis in Eastern Orthodox teachings before they can procreate, so that "lust" will be absent, just like St.Joachim and St.Anne did, that's why they produced an "immaculate body" from the "uncorrupted seed".

Comment: Does ccc398 really teach that pre-fall humans needed to be "divinized"? Does it in fact teach that anyone other than Mary's parents should be or were divinized?

Comment: My comment is 5 years old, and it was apparently a sarcastic one, but I think my point was: Lust is the illicit desire for sex,so if sex is illicit, then wanting it is lust, not that all sex is necessarily borne of lust, only that illicit sex is.  But I suppose one could make the argument that a couple could undertake (consensual), illicit sex, without wanting it, although that seems far-fetched.

Comment: @Flimzy the only question is, if you know that biblical scholars now understand Garden of Eden as the Temple of God, the First Sanctuary of God where Adam  & Eve worship and commune with God. Can they do a consensual sexual act in a sacred place of the paradise? If they did then they desecrated and defiled the garden.right?

Comment: @jongricafort: There are so many assumptions and opinions in that statement, I don't even know how to respond.

Answer (score 12):

I believe that you are referring to the theory that the original sin was sex. This, however, is not Biblically true. Before the fall, God said:

> And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and
>   **multiply**, and **replenish the earth**, and subdue it: and have dominion
>   over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every
>   living thing that moveth upon the earth.
>
> Genesis 1:28

How could they multiply if sex was a sin? The original sin, according to the Bible, was disobedience. (See Genesis 3)

EDIT: Because the question was edited, my answer has now been edited too. I have ran into a few people, mostly from the Catholic faith,  who believed in this teaching. As far as I know, this is not Catholic doctrine, they just had been misinformed.

Comment: The word "be fruitful and multiply' lacks the exhortation that God said to Abraham and other Patriarch, the complete word is "multiply your seed". The word "seed" is missing in God's words to Adam & Eve. Plus the issue here is "defilement of the Temple of God", what kind of "actual sin" can defile the Temple of God situated in the east. God had planted a garden in the east, it is the Sanctuary of God. Can Adam & Eve "multiply or procreate" right at the very Sanctuary of God? Remember it is a place of worship and communion with God.

Comment: @jongricafort I don't really agree with a few things in your comment. First, how does the command, be fruitful and multiply, lack exhortation? It is a command. He did NOT say "you may be fruitful and multiply" which may lack exhortation. Second, how could humans multiply if not through sex, which was made by God Himself? Third, name one verse in the Bible that says the Garden of Eden is the Sanctuary of God. This is the first I've heard of such a thing. Fourth, are you saying that God did not want Adam and Eve to multiply in the very place that God Himself put them? It's just not Biblical.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any group who believes this. Adam and Eve's sin is regarding disobedience. The only other teaching (which is false) about anything in connection to the events that unfolded in The Garden of Eden was the first mate (first wife) belief. Sex itself what produces life. This is between mates, for if it was sin, it would not make sense for the earth to be populated. It only becomes sin if brazen conduct and immorality is involved, then you have a problem. But nothing of this sort took place in The Garden of Eden, despite Adam and Eve being kicked out of the garden, moreover, they were already a couple.